# How would you convert this to valid VB.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I found an article on [removing whitespace](http://arranmaclean.wordpress.com/2010/08/10/minify-html-with-net-mvc-actionfilter/) from my markup in ASP.NET MVC, however, when I use the code converter, the "function" is not properly converted

```
public class WhitespaceFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

            var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            response.Filter = new WhiteSpaceFilter(response.Filter, s =>
                    {
                        s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s+", " ");
                        s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\n\s*", "\n");
                        s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*\>\s*\<\s*", "><");
                        s = Regex.Replace(s, @"<!--(.*?)-->", "");   //Remove comments

                        // single-line doctype must be preserved 
                        var firstEndBracketPosition = s.IndexOf(">");
                        if (firstEndBracketPosition >= 0)
                        {
                            s = s.Remove(firstEndBracketPosition, 1);
                            s = s.Insert(firstEndBracketPosition, ">");
                        }
                        return s;
                    });

            }

    }
```

This is what gets generated by the Telerik code converter,

```
    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(ByVal filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)

        Dim request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request
        Dim response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response

        response.Filter = New WhiteSpaceFilter(response.Filter, Function(s) Do
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "\s+", " ")
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "\s*\n\s*", vbLf)
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "\s*\>\s*\<\s*", "><")
        s = Regex.Replace(s, "<!--(.*?)-->", "")
        'Remove comments 
        ' single-line doctype must be preserved 
        Dim firstEndBracketPosition = s.IndexOf(">")
        If firstEndBracketPosition >= 0 Then
            s = s.Remove(firstEndBracketPosition, 1)
            s = s.Insert(firstEndBracketPosition, ">")
        End If
        Return s
        End Function)

    End Sub
```

However the `Function(s) Do` is invalid. I don't know how to pass a function as a parameter in a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically a lambda expression in c#. : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx 

 You need to look at how to do the same in VB.net : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a delegate for this in VB.NET [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vbcon/html/vbup1048.asp) and [this](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/printdelegate.html) should help you.